# Can't set value of input

Tags: javascript

I couldn't set value  of `input type="datetime-local"` this is my code

```
document.getElementById("time_Out").defaultValue =  document.getElementById("DateOut"+id).innerHTML;
```

Comment: This isn't php and i don't see jquery. Add the tags properly

Answer (score 0):

use getvalue instead of innerHTML, inner is to write, and i guess that you want to read

```
document.getElementById("time_Out").defaultValue = document.getElementById("DateOut"+id).getValue();
```

otherwhise if you want to set time_Out's value in DateOut:

```
cument.getElementById("DateOut"+id).innerHTML(document.getElementById("time_Out").getValue());
```